# How to map abstract JPA base entity?

Tags: jpa, mapping

Rather simple case, yet I'm having issues finding a working mapping. Example stripped down to the very basic problem.

Two entities: Player and Coach. Both have a date of birth.

**Database**

```
Table PL // Player    
NUMERIC plid AUTOINCREMENT

Table CO // Coach
NUMERIC coid AUTOINCREMENT

Table BASE
NUMERIC enid - playerId or coachId
CHAR    entp - 'PL' for Player, 'CO' for Coach
DATE    bdt
```

**Java**

```
Abstract BaseClass {
    Date dateOfBirth;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="PL")
Player extends BaseClass {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    @Column(name="plid")
    Long playerId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="CO")
Coach extends BaseClass {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    @Column(name="coid")
    Long coachId;
}
```

How can we map the BaseEntity class to persist Player.dateOfBirth in table BASE as `1, 'PL', 1970-01-01`?

Comment: not my business, but why do you need CO and PL? You could just get rid of these tables and use only BASE

Comment: Did I not say it's a stipped down example?

Comment: Yes, but still looks weird for me :-)

Comment: But supposing CO and PL are huge classes with very little in common, I'd still prefer to reuse the autoincrement in the base class and use the flag to differentiate one subclass from another

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question but if you're so sure of your idea, create these classes, generate id in the base class table and then try to override the id attribute, so that enid gets saved in plid and coid. Good luck.

Comment: I think @csn approach down below is the one I'd use. In fact that's exactly what I am doing in my current project :-) I have an abstract base class that uses @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED) and the concrete classes under it has what is specific to each one. You don't have to keep different columns for the specific subclasses IDs. The ID is unique anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use InheritanceType.JOINED which allows you to keep common data in base table and subclasses can have data specific to their needs.

In your example, 'entp' can act as discriminator column. You should annotate your classes as follows:

```
    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
    @DiscriminatorColumn(name="ENT_TYPE")
    @Table(name="BASE")
    public abstract class BaseClass {
          @Id
          Long id;
          @Column(name = "ENT_TYPE")
          String entp;
          ...
    }

    @Entity
    @DiscriminatorValue("PL")
    @Table(name="PL")
    public class Player extends BaseClass {

    }

    @Entity
    @DiscriminatorValue("CO")
    @Table(name="CO")
    public class Coach extends BaseClass {

    }
```

Comment: Looks promising. I have lots of things going on in my code, so need a day to get to try this.